# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Channel> to Iterable<ICleanable>

Tags: java, generics, interface, parameter-passing, type-mismatch

Java context:

Class: `Channel implements ICleanable`
Variable: `Set<Channel> channels = new HashSet<>()`

I need to call this method with an array of `Iterable` as parameter:

```
void unexport(Iterable<ICleanable>[] cleanables)
```

But I cannot devise how to write the call. This version doesn't work:

```
unexport(new Iterable<ICleanable>[] { channels })
```

The compiler says: "`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Channel> to Iterable<ICleanable>`"

Help would be appreciated (and/or reference to learning material). Thanks.

---

EDIT. Now that I've got the answer, I can summarize where I was wrong.

I had a problem with generics and subtypping. This is a beginner error (which is exactly what I'm). Clue:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();  
List<Object> lo = ls; // Illegal, a List<String> is not a List<Object>!  
lo.add(new Object());  
String s = ls.get(0); // Attempts to assign an Object to a String!
```

A `List<String>` **cannot be** a `List<Object>`, otherwise the type safety void be void.
This is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html).

I had a second problem with array of generics.

```
unexport(new Iterable<ICleanable>[] { channels })
```

It is not possible to create an array of Iterable. This is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays). The error on type conversion prevented this second error to be detected by the compiler before correction of the former.

In my case I ended up with this:

```
void unexport(List<List<? extends ICleanable>> cleanables) {...}
Channel implements ICleanable;
List<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<? extends ITVCleanable>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(channels);
unexport(list);
```

Comment: Does `channels.iterator();` work? Hang on, why is it an `Iterable<ICleanable>[]`?

Comment: You're also trying to create generic array there.

Comment: @doctorlove. With you suggestion: `cannot convert from Iterator<Channel> to Iterable<ICleanable>`. In the method I want to process a list of unknown size of (Set of Iterable). I have though of using ... but it creates a heap pollution door, so the array. Channel actually extends UnicastRemoteObject and implements ICleanable. The method is interested only by the ICleanable features.

Comment: Generics = parameterized types + parameterized methods + wildcards. Easy to understand concepts. but generics do not seem to fit well with the rest of Java: numerous limitations, exceptions and special cases lead to a big spaghetti plate. Those cases make little sense, or are not consistent, hence are difficult to remember. A short + comprehensive presentation of these cases, and the rational of their existence would be superior to multiple incomplete explanations about a specific case. Does someone knows about such summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create a [generic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation) at `new Iterable<ICleanable>[]`. You can't create a generic array directly, so instead you can do this:

```
unexport((Iterable<ICleanable>[]) new Iterable[] { channels });
```

Comment: Thanks! arrrhh if I could get this once for all :-)